# Reverse Engineering cameraParameters object

Tags: matlab

Is there a matlab function to reverse engineer the cameraParameters object from  existing pairs of world- and image coordinates.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Read the help for [cameraParameters](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/cameraparameters-class.html). In the example which is provided for the help, it states the following (bold added).

> This example shows you how to use the cameraParameters object in a workflow to remove distortion from an image. The example creates a cameraParameters object manually. In practice, use the **estimateCameraParameters** or the **cameraCalibrator** app to derive the object.

In the help for `estimateCameraParameters`, you will find full instructions on how to use points determined from calibration images (typically a checkerboard is used) to estimate a `cameraParameters` object.

If you couldn't find this in the help files in your version of MATLAB, it may be that you are using an older version which does not have these functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I dont want and also cannot use a calibration image to estimate a cameraParamters object.


But i already have world coordinates for several points  and the references in camera coordinates for these points.

Now i want to reverse engineer a cameraParamters object.